# product topology and discrete space

Tags: general-topology

Let $K$ be discrete space consisting of two numbers $0,1$. Let $A$ be infinite set and let $X$ be product space $K^{B(A)}$. 
(a) Let $J$ be finite subset of $A$; suppose $J$ has $p$ elements. For each subset $H$ of $J$, let $M_H$ be set of subsets $L$ of $A$ such that $L\cap J=H$; the $M_H$ forms partition $\omega_J$ of $B(A)$ into $2^p$ elements. Let $F_J$be subset of $X$ consisting of those points $x_L$;such that $x_L=x_M$ whenever $L$ and $M$ belong to same set of partition $\omega_J$. $F_J$ is finite set, with $2^{2^p}$ elements. If $F$ is the finite union of $F_J$ as $J$ runs through all finite subsets of $A$. Show that $F$ and $A$ have same cardinality. (b)$F$  is dense in $X$.

Comment: What is $B(A)$?

Comment: i have deduced the following : let cardinality of $A=q$.  and given cardinality of $J=p$ . i have come to point that $2^p<2^q$.

Comment: $B(A)$ is set of all subsets of $A$

Comment: ... more commonly known as $P(A)$.

Comment: If $A$ is infinite, then the cardinality of the finite subsets of $A$ is also $|A|$ (as $|A|+|A|^2 + |A|^3  + \ldots \le \aleph_0 \cdot |A|= |A|$). And a union of $|A|$ many finite subsets is still at most size $|A|$.

Comment: $F$ is dense because it intersects every basic open subset of $X$ (which depends on *finitely many* coordinates, recall).

Comment: how come $F_J$ has $2^{2^p}$ elements?

Comment: is it because $F$ agrees with $M_H$ ?

Comment: prof, if we could have small discussion on question 4 and 5 , paragraph 4 from nicholas bourbaki's general topology, it will clear me. this is actually question 5 from the book

Answer (score 4):

Henno Brandsma has dealt with the cardinality question in the comments. The density question takes a bit more work; I’ll point you in the right direction.

If $\mathscr{F}$ is a finite subset of $\wp(A)$ (a more usual notation for your $B(A)$), and $\varphi:\mathscr{F}\to K$, let

$$B(\mathscr{F},\varphi)=\{x\in X:x_L=\varphi(L)\text{ for each }L\in\mathscr{F}\}\;;$$

the set of these sets $B(\mathscr{F},\varphi)$ is a base for the product topology on $X$. To show that $F$ is dense in $X$, it suffices to show that $B(\mathscr{F},\varphi)\cap F\ne\varnothing$.

For each $\mathscr{S}\subseteq\mathscr{F}$ such that $(\bigcap\mathscr{S})\setminus\bigcup(\mathscr{F}\setminus\mathscr{S})\ne\varnothing$ choose an

$$a_{\mathscr{S}}\in\left(\bigcap\mathscr{S}\right)\setminus\bigcup\left(\mathscr{F}\setminus\mathscr{S}\right)\;,$$

and let $J$ be the set of these $a_{\mathscr{S}}$; clearly $J$ is a finite subset of $A$, so $F_J\subseteq F$.

> **Claim:** There is an $x\in F_J$ such that $x(L)=\varphi(L)$ for each $L\in\mathscr{F}$ and hence such that $x\in B(\mathscr{F},\varphi)\cap F$.

I’ll leave it to you to prove the claim; note that if $L\in\mathscr{F}$, then $L\cap J=\{a_{\mathscr{S}}:L\in\mathscr{S}\}$.

Comment: i completely understood, now only stands last doubt why $M_{H_1}\cap M_{H_2}=\phi$

Comment: @singh: Because if $L$ is a subset of $A$ such that $L\cap J=H_1$, and $H_1\ne H_2$, then $L\cap J\ne H_2$. Thus, if $L\in M_{H_1}$, then $M\notin M_{H_2}$.

Comment: derived question to this is. : Let $K$ be discrete space of two numbers $0,1$. Let $A$ be infinite set, and let $X$ be product space $K^A$. Let $V=\prod_{\alpha \in A}V_{\alpha}$ be elementary set in $X$., if $h$ is number of indices $\alpha$ such that $V_{\alpha}\neq K$, put $\mu(V)=2^{-h}$. Now how to show if $U_1,\dots ,U_n$ are pair wise disjoint elementary sets, then $\sum_{k=1}^n \mu(U_k) \leq 1$. \\

Comment: the hint in the book is to write each $U_k$ in form of $W_k\times K^B$, where $B$ is complement of finite subset of $A$, and $W_k$ is finite set, count up the number of points in $W_k$. this is one of the difficult problems in N bourbaki